# Arabic: Unicode: how to stack fatha kasra damma

Tags: unicode, latex, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, arabic

I am using LibreOffice to type arabic, but if what I am asking cannot be obtained with
LibreOffice then I would like to know whether it is possible in LaTeX, because I have
seen this in a book, but do not know how to do it. I want to type an arabic consonant
with all three diacritics **fatha, kasra, and damma** as in the following picture:\

This combination is not possible in standard Arabic, but I have seen it in a textbook
that wanted to show this combination to convey the information that either one of the
three diacritics could appear in such position in the case of the given verb form.

[image]

As a last resort, could the effect be achieved by means of a Unicode combination?
Since the text book had the combination, it must sure be possible to achieve the
effect some way or another.

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

ﻓﻌَُِل

To achieve this, I used the middle form of ع which is ـعـ by looking it up on Character Map. Then magically, it somehow worked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This solution seems to achieve the effect I was seeking to some extent, except for the fatha and the damma look superimposed rather than separate in all the MS Word fonts I have tied out.

Comment: @JohnSonderson Yeah, but in the browser it shows nicely. It is rather a bad hack. Unicode is full of tricks and I think advance publishing software and text shapers are quite powerful to customize.